# Define common lower bounds of parameters

Tags: scala, generics, types, type-bounds

In the following function, the Scala compiler is able to define the return type to the lowest common supertype of the values used in the if/else expression:

```
def cond(b: Boolean, t: A, f: B) = if (b) t else f
```

Considering the following hierarchy:

```
class X
class A extends X
class B extends X
```

the function `cond` above is defined as returning a value of type `X`.

However, if `A` and `B` are type parameters in the definition of the `cond` function, its return type is `Any`:

```
def cond[A, B](b: Boolean, t: A, f: B) = if (b) t else f
```

**Is it possible to make the compiler use the lowest common supertype of the type parameters?**

I tried some variations of the following, without success:

```
def cond[A, B, R >: A with B](b: Boolean, t: A, f: B): R = if (b) t else f
def cond[A, B, R](b: Boolean, t: A, f: B)(implicit ev1: A <:< R, ev2: B <:< R): R = if (b) t else f
```

**EDIT**: The question above is oversimplified. In fact my real problem had one of the type parameters already resolved:

```
class C[A](b: Boolean, t: A) {
  def cond[B](f: B) = if(b) t else f
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need the exacta types of the arguments, then the following will usually suffice:

```
def cond[T](b: Boolean, t: T, f: T) = if (b) t else f
```

Scala will automatically upcast the types of the arguments to their least upper bound (LUB):

```
scala> cond(true, new A, new B)
res0: X = A@74a59bb6
```

---

But if you need the exact types, for example for implicit resolution, I believe the following trick should work:

```
def cond[A, B, C >: A](b: Boolean, t: A, f: B with C): C = if (b) t else f
```

Here `A` and `B` are exact types of the arguments, and `C` is their LUB. `C` has the constraint to be the supertype of `A`: `C >: A`, but it also should be the type of the second argument, because it's defined as `f: B with C`, and thus it is inferred as the LUB of `A` and `B`.

We can check correct type inference with this definition with the following code:

```
import reflect.runtime.universe._
def cond[A, B, C >: A](b: Boolean, t: A, f: B with C)(
  implicit ta: TypeTag[A], 
           tb: TypeTag[B], 
           tc: TypeTag[C]
): C = {
  println(ta)
  println(tb)
  println(tc)
  if (b) t else f
}

scala> cond(true, new A, new B)
TypeTag[A]
TypeTag[B]
TypeTag[X]
res5: X = A@f0ad2ea
```

Answer (score 1):

You can apply upper type bounds to A and B,if you know LUB statically.

```
def cond[A <: C, B <: C,C](b: Boolean, t: A, f: B) = if (b) t else f
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @nikhil and @Kolmar answers I could come up to this solution:

```
class C[A](b: Boolean, t: A) {
  def cond[B <: R, R >: A](f: B): R = if(b) t else f
}
```